# My Search Filter Lightning Web Component isn't Working and I'm Not Sure Why

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning, javascript, xml

The purpose of my LWC is to search the name of an account and return a list of associated contacts. Every time I try and search for an account in the search bar nothing happens, and I am not sure why.

Can anyone see what is going wrong? Here is a screen shot of the component along with the code. Any help would be most appreciated.

LWC Screenshot:
[image]

LWC HTML file:

```
<template>
  <lightning-card
    title="How to display the Contacts based on Account Name in LWC"
    custom-icon="custom:icon13"
  >
    <div class="slds slds-p-horizontal--medium">
      <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-12 slds-m-bottom--medium">
          <lightning-Input
            type="search"
            placeholder="Search..."
            value={accountName}
            name="accountName"
            class="accountName"
            onchange={handleChangeAccName}
          ></lightning-Input>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-m-top--medium"
          style="margin-top: 19px; margin-left: 10px"
        >
          <lightning-button
            label="Search Account Name"
            size="small"
            variant="brand"
            onclick={handleAccountSearch}
            icon-name="utility:search"
            icon-position="right"
          ></lightning-button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2>
        Account Name :- <span><strong>{currentAccountName}</strong></span>
      </h2>
      <br />
      <h3>
        <strong><span style="color: brown">{dataNotFound}</span></strong>
      </h3>
      <br />
      <h2
        class="slds-m-bottom--x-small"
        style="color: darkslateblue; font-weight: bold"
      >
        Displaying Contacts Records based on Account Name
      </h2>
      <table
        class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered"
        border="1"
        cellspacing="0"
        cellpadding="0"
        bordercolor="#ccc"
        style="border-collapse: collapse"
      >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Description</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <template for:each={records} for:item="conItem">
            <tr key={conItem.Id}>
              <td>{conItem.FirstName}</td>
              <td>{conItem.LastName}</td>
              <td>{conItem.Phone}</td>
              <td>{conItem.Account.Name}</td>
            </tr>
          </template>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
  </lightning-card>
</template>



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFcsv.jpg
```

LWC JS File:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from "lwc";
import retrieveContactData from "@salesforce/apex/fetchAllRelatedRecords.retrieveContact";
export default class DisplayContactsOnAccountName extends LightningElement {
  @track currentName;
  @track searchName;
  handleChangeAccName(event) {
    this.currentAccountName = event.target.value;
  }
  handleAccountSearch() {
    this.searchName = this.currentName;
  }
  @track records;
  @track dataNotFound;
  @wire(retrieveContactData, { keySearch: "$searchName" })
  wireRecord({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
      this.records = data;
      this.error = undefined;
      this.dataNotFound = "";
      if (this.records == "") {
        this.dataNotFound = "There is no Contact found related to Account name";
      }
    } else {
      this.error = error;
      this.data = undefined;
    }
  }
}
```

LWC XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<apiVersion>56.0</apiVersion>
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<targets>
<target>lightning__AppPage</target>
<target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
<target>lightning__HomePage</target>
<target>lightning__Tab</target>
</targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

LWC Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class fetchAllRelatedRecords {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Contact> retrieveContact(string keySearch){
        List<Contact> mycontactList = [Select Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, Account.Name From Contact Where Account.Name=:keySearch];
        return mycontactList;
    }
}
```

LWC Apex Class XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexClass xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>56.0</apiVersion>
    <status>Active</status>
</ApexClass>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
handleChangeAccName(event) {
  this.currentAccountName = event.target.value;
}
```

Should be:

```
handleChangeAccName(event) {
  this.currentName = event.target.value;
}
```

When programming, make sure you pay close attention to variable names. This is a pretty easy and common mistake to make.

Comment: That worked for me. Thank you very much :)